# Join an Azure Communication Services Chat as a Teams user

Tags: python, azure, azure-communication-services

I'm trying to build a proof of concept application using Azure Communication Services.

I have followed the chat hero example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/samples/chat-hero-sample for basic chat setup and I have that all working.
I now want to join the chat thread as a teams user instead of creating a new chat identity.

I've added the ability to exchange a teams token for an ACS identity token as described in the  manage-teams-idenity quickstart: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-python-quickstarts/blob/main/manage-teams-identity-mobile-and-desktop/exchange-communication-access-tokens.py

From there, I create a MicrosoftTeamsUserIdentifier object, and call
chat_client_thread.add_participants with a list of the participants to add.

The add_participants call is failing with an underlying 403 error: 'Permissions check failed' for the added participant, although the overall add_participants call succeeds with 201.

If I attempt to use the AAD OID to create a CommunicationUserIdentifer object I get an error saying the Participant format is invalid, so I know that I need to use the MicrosoftTeamsUserIdentifier Identifier type.

I cannot find any documentation on what privileges or permissions I need to tweak.  None of the examples discuss this workflow.

Is adding a teams user to an ACS chat supported?
If so, what permissions do I need to check or adjust to allow them to join?